# How do I run a function over and over by using parameters?

Tags: javascript, parameters

My case:

```
function randomLetter(){
    var random = letter[Math.floor(Math.random()*26)];
    return random; 
}

function randomWord(wordLength){
    var random = randomLetter() + randomLetter() + randomLetter();
    return random; 
}
```

How do I write a code that run the `randomLetter()` function x times using parametes.
Example: I write 3 in the parameter, and the function will give me three random letters.
So instead of writing `randomLetter() + randomLetter() + randomLetter()`, I will just write `randomWord(3)`, and I will get three random letters.

Comment: [`for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression]) { ... }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: Please take a look at a few JavaScript tutorials. Repeatedly running the same code X times (loops) are a fundamental part of any programming language.

Comment: for loop, while loop, recursion, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach, which buffers each letter into an array and returns the joined array.

```
function randomWord(wordLength){
    var letters = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
        letters.push(randomLetter());
    }

    return letters.join("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for-loop:

```
function randomWord(x){

    var random = [];

    for(var a = 0; a < x; a++){
        random[a] = randomLetter();
    }

    return random.join("");
}
```

Comment: @EliRichardson I don't see why not. Can you explain?

Comment: @TVASO JavaScript is loosly typed. The `int` is invalid. This looks a little like Java code.

Comment: JavaScript isn't statically typed. It has no "int" keyword.

Comment: @TVASO and in the for loop... :)

Comment: `random` is never declared. The loop would be __overriding__ the value of `random`. The return value can't be a string like that... How this got an upvote is beyond me.

Comment: @Cerbrus Indeed, ToLoen has changed the code snipped. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

For this you could use a for loop like:

```
function randomWord(wordLength){
  var random =''
  for (var i = 0, i<wordLength, i++) {
    random += randomLetter();
  }
  return random; 
}
```

the first parameter in the parentheses after the 'for' keyword initializes the i variable with 0. The next value `i<wordLength` is the stop condition, which will test at the beginning of each run if the condition is still true, otherwise it will stop looping. The third `i++` is what runs every time a loop finishes, in this case it increments i by one, which is identical to `i = i + 1`.

here is some more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Or recursion:

```js
var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
function randomLetter() {
  return letters.charAt(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)) % letters.length)
}

function getLetters(count) {
  if (count-- < 1) return "";
  return getLetters(count) + randomLetter() + ","
}

document.getElementById("output").innerText = getLetters(4)
```

```html
<div id="output" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another recursive solution:

```js
function randomLetter() {
  return ('qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm')[Math.floor(Math.random()*26)];
}

function randomWord(wordLength) {
  return (wordLength > 0) ? (randomWord(wordLength - 1) + randomLetter()) : '';
}

console.log( randomWord(10) );
```